# Chromium fonts are buggy

Tags: fonts, kde, chromium

In Ubuntu 10.10 I changed KDE applications fonts settings on «systemsettings» (I enabled anti-aliasing, I think this is the problem), and all fonts in Chromium Browser do not render as they would, they look ugly. I restored default settings and all remained ugly. So I purged all KDE applications and all remained the same. I purged, deleted all config files and reinstalled chromium and the fonts are still ugly and rare. In the rest of my desktop and web browsers are as they used to look.

Here some pics.
Chromium Now
[image]

Midori (Chromium used to look like this)
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I solved it. As I enabled anti-aliasing and I couldn't disable it manually I only had to create a new `.fonts.conf` (well, I deleted the old one only) in my home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check your home directory for a file like `.gtkrc-2.0-kde4` or `.gtkrc-2.0`.  Also check under `.kde/share/` as this is where KDE hides its configurations for applications and fonts.

Often these are used for integrating GTK apps into KDE style (ie QtCurve).  These files sometimes contain font information.

Remove those files (or backup to a new filename), log out, log back in, and see if the same situation presents itself.